# Laravel storage symlink on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting, symlink, shared-hosting

I'm having problem with setting up storage link on shared hosting.
Because of that I can't load any image from storage folder.
My public folder is renamed to web and when I try this:
**ln -s storage/app/public/ web/storage**
my issue still remains. Also, I have access to the console on the server.
Any help would be appreciated

** Edit -> everything worked fine on localhost (before moving to production)

Comment: Laravel doesn't have a `web` folder - is that something your host provides? Does `ln -s` work or does it show an error? What does `ls -la web/storage` show?

Comment: @ceejayoz web folder is just renamed public folder from laravel, ln command seems to be working but doesn't solve my problem, I'll post result from that ls command in 10mins

Comment: If you put a file in `storage/app/public` manually, like `storage/app/public/foo.jpg`, are you able to access it at `example.com/storage/foo.jpg` in the browser? What do you get if you try?

Comment: So, ls -la web/storage shows this, lrwxrwxrwx 1 uid1122132 gid1122132 19 Feb  7 22:36 web/storage -> storage/app/public/ and when I tried to access them in browser I get access forbidden. Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with badly linked symlink.
All I had to do was:
**ln -sfv ../storage/app/public/ storage** from web directory